# Why when i use jquery slideDown and Up function, the element cannot be padding or it will be an error

Tags: jquery, css, slidetoggle, slideup, slidedown

Below is my code with padding

> '#'expand{    padding: 16px;    display: none;    background-color: #fff; }

when i put slidetoggle to this element, it seems like the padding animated with the slide

Instead i need a put an child div element and put padding in the child element, Can I ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure this is what you want, but I'm assuming you want to slide a child `div` into a parent `div` with padding.  You could do something like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="expand">Stuff goes here</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#expand{      
    display: none;    
    background-color: yellow;
}
#container {
    padding:16px;
    background-color:black;
}
```

(Colors are there for emphasis of the padded elements)

JavaScript:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $("#expand").slideToggle();
});
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/hqVdQ/

Hope that helps!